# YouTubePartner API for .Net not found

Tags: .net, youtube-api

My main objective is to get the assets list from you tube cms in csv format and persist information in database using .Net .So I have looked into docs for youtube partner at : [https://developers.google.com/youtube/partner/](https://developers.google.com/youtube/partner/.)

The example given in document is for python which uses youtube partner library.But when I searched for YouTube partner library for .Net,I am unable to find it.

Can any one tell me that where I could find this library?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

I think this is what you are looking for: https://developers.google.com/api-client-library/dotnet/apis/

In various request types, the comment for the **onBehalfOfContentOwner** property refers to CMS and content partners.

Another place to start:
https://developers.google.com/youtube/v3/

Comment: Yes you are right about onBehalfOfContentOwner property,but I could not find that how to get assets list of content owner which we can see in CMS account.Do you know about this?